# best way database management in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i started learn database mysql
im confusing how to manage all tables in one page

i've tried datatables but still not like what i want
i dont know the keyword for searching in google

all tables always have "visitor_id"

**example :**

list visitor_id

| visitor_id | visitor_ip | visitor_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192.168.1.122 | SG |
| 2 | 192.168.1.11 | UK |
| 3 | 192.168.1.9 | CN |
| 4 | 192.168.1.89 | UK |

file list with file_id and visitor_id

file_path is null, and visitor_id have 2 file_path

| file_id | visitor_id | file_path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | /hello.img |
| 2 | 2 | /p.img |
| 3 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 4 | /hii.img |
| 5 | 2 | /hello.img |

i save in the stats tables

look in the stats_file, value is 2 because visitor_id 2 is have two file

and if dont have file, stats_file is 0

| stats_id | visitor_id | stats_file |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

so, i want output like

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D7nH.png)

visitor_id 3 is hidden because dont have file

Comment: I suggest you make some tutorials...

Comment: It's always hard to find a good starting place. Are you using any PHP framework? If so, I would suggest trying to google: **FRAMEWORK_NAME + database management** , Otherwise **php databases management** would be a good start. Once, you have a basic idea of what you are working with, it will be easier to navigate.

Comment: i update my question, i dont know how to post in here. first time im asking in stackoverflow,now i learn with code igniter

Comment: Just use SQL to get what you want. Joining related tables

Comment: thanks everybody, i will googling now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everybody
,solved using SQL joining related tables

```
SELECT f.file_id,f.visitor_id,v.visitor_ip,f.file_path,v.visitor_country FROM file AS f LEFT JOIN visitor AS v ON  f.visitor_id=v.visitor_id
```

from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: as you are learning codeigniter, have a look at: [CI3.x selecting data, join:](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join) and [CI 4.x selecting data, join](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#selecting-data). Also [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is very useful to understand joins